# How do I use VBA vlookup function to fill out data for multiple columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 Excel files.

I currently use a vlookup function for multiple columns that references the same vlookup value and table from a different Excel workbook. Is there a VBA code that will allow me to use a vlookup that will return/fill out multiple columns?

More specifically I would want this:

Use a vlookup VBA code that references the vlookup value (an ID#) from my current file then references the table from a different worksheet. The result should fill out 3 separate columns.

Comment: You write three separate vlookups, one for each column. A single formula can only "fill out" a single cell.

Comment: VLookup can be mixed along with Match to fill multiple columns with the same formula (Match would replace the column parameter) if the headers are the same on both excels. `=VLOOKUP(ID,RANGE,MATCH(HEADER,RANGEHEADERS,0),0)`